# Tameness in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ of the subset consisting of matrices of positive determinant

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, real-algebraic-geometry

The Lie group $GL(n)$ being a manifold is locally path-connected. Consider its connected component of the identity $C\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$.  What is a good way of showing that $C$ is *a tame subset* of $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ i.e., if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that if the Euclidean norm $|x-y|<\delta$ for $x,y\in C$ then there is a path of length $<\epsilon$ in $C$ joining $x$ and $y$? An earlier version of the question used the term "locally path-connected as a subset" which some users found confusing. Note that local path-connectedness of subsets of Euclidean space is a completely standard usage.  In particular the "comb" in the plane is not locally path connected in the plane precisely in this sense; see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_space).

Answer (score 3):

The proposed fact is true, this is how I'd prove it.

The set $M_n(\mathbb R)\setminus\{0\}$ retracts on the unit sphere $S$ by linear rescaling $M\mapsto \frac{M}{||M||}$. Let $\hat C$ be the image of $C$.

Now $\Delta:=\{\det M=0\}$ is an algebraic hypersurface in $S$ (because the determinant is homogeneous) and $\hat C$ is a connected component of $S\setminus\Delta$. Let $d$ be the Euclidean distance induced on $S$.

Assume that $C$ is not tame. This gives a sequence $(M_n,N_n)_n$ of matrices in $S$ such that $d(M_n,N_n)<\frac{1}{n}$ and $M_n$ and $N_n$ cannot be joined by a path of length less than some $\epsilon$. It is so because what happens along half-lines $\mathbb R_{>0} M$ is tame. Up to extract a subsequence we can form the limit $M\in S$.

- Clearly $M\in\Delta$ for otherwise one can take a ball of small radius $r>0$ in $\hat C$ around $M$, and all points in this ball are linked by a path of length at most $Kr$ for some universal constant $K=K_n$.
- If $M$ belongs to a regular point of $\Delta$ then locally you can find an analytic rectification of $\Delta$ onto a coordinate axis in $\mathbb R^{n^2-1}$. Here again a small half-ball will give a contradiction (the fact that the rectification is sufficiently smooth implies that the distance is not too distorted). The point of the argument here is that you cannot "reach the other side" (even by taking a long detour) without crossing $\Delta$ itself.
- If $M$ belongs to the singular set of $\Delta$, you apply the same argument after desingularization of the hypersurface. According to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1173392/resolution-of-singularities-of-the-determinant-hypersurface) the projection on the second factor
  $$R~:~\mathbb P_{n-1}(\mathbb R)\times S\longrightarrow S $$
  is a resolution of singularities when restricted to the set $X:=\{([v],M)~:~Mv=0\}$. Indeed $R(X)=\Delta$ and  $X$ is smooth, for the differential of the map $$ \begin{eqnarray} F~:~\mathbb R^n\times M_n(\mathbb R) \longrightarrow &  \mathbb R^n \\ (v,M)\longmapsto &  Mv \end{eqnarray} $$ is $(h,A)\mapsto Mh+Av$, which has maximal rank $n$ if $v\neq0$ (take $h:=0$).

Comment: Are you using CAD here?

Comment: Cylindrical algebraic decomposition. I was just trying to determine more explicitly what sort of algebraic-geometric background goes into your proposed solution.

Comment: It seems to me that your quotient of $GL_n$ is not compact (the function $tr^2/det$ is not bounded) and that instead something like the set of $n$-tuples of linearly independent unit vectors needs to be used in the argument.

Comment: I was just talking about the union of the two sets $A$ and $B$ where $A=\{(x,y,z): x^2+y^2\leq 1; z=0\}$ and $B=\{(x,y,z): x^2+z^2\leq 1; y=0\}$.

Comment: @user83633: yes, obviously my answer was not well-written. I simplified it so that everything happens in ambient space.

Comment: Points near the origin in different "octants" are close for the Euclidean norm but far away if you want to connect them by paths in the complement.  I am glad I was able to express myself properly in the end :-)

Comment: Just look at a figure-8 in the plane.  Choose a point "above" the center and another point "below" the center.  You can't join them by a short path.

Comment: Very naive question, since I don't understand the last desingularization step: Could this be done on induction by dimension? The answer given seems to give a correct answer if the limiting marix $M$ has corank 1. Is there an argument now for corank 2?

Comment: @MikhailKatz: good point. Normal crossings seem to pose problems. Maybe Deane's suggestion could work for the determinant case.

Comment: @DeaneYang: I edited the answer to address the remaining cases.

Comment: @MikhailKatz: maybe it'd be a good idea to clean up some comments. I did mine, could you please consider doing some of yours?

Comment: LoïcTeyssier, in principle this might be a good idea but there unfortunately exists an objectionable practice by some of the editors to delete not merely their own compomising comments but also the comments by other users. Therefore I prefer to leave my comments in place particularly as they are still relevant in this case. @AsafKaragila

Answer (score 1):

In the paper

- Edward Bierstone: Differentiable functions, BOLL. SOC. BRAS. MAT.,VOL 11 N 2 (1980), 139-190

one finds the following theorem, which states that for subanalytic subsets (those given by equations and $\le$-inequalities involving real analytic functions) with dense interior the interior distance is locally Hoelder continuous with respect to Euclidean distance.

Theorem 6.17. Let $V$ be an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$, and $A$ a closed subanalytic subset of $V$ such that $Int(A)$ is dense in $A$. For every compact subset $L$ of $A$, there exists $c > 0$ and an integer $\alpha \ge 1$ such that any two points $b, y \in L$
can be joined by a semianalytic arc $\sigma$ in $A$ such that:

- (1) $|\sigma| < c|b - y|^{1/\alpha}$
- (2) $\sigma$ intersects $\partial A$ in at most finitely many points.

Comment: Thanks.   Could you possibly comment on how this takes care of the examples I mentioned above, such as the union of two disks in 3-space, and the figure-8 in the plane.  I guess one has to look up the definition of "subanalytic"?

Answer (score 0):

This applies to the earlier version of the question:

It is an open subset since the determinant function is continuous, and open subsets are locally path-connected.

Comment: Consider the complement $C$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of the closed interval $[-1,1]$ on the $x$-axis.  Is $C$ locally path connected as a subset of the plane?

Comment: Please delete your incorrect answer because it is generating downvotes.

Comment: Yes, of course. It is *open* and connected.

Comment: It is connected but it is not locally path-connected *as a subset of the plane*. Please re-read my question. @LoïcTeyssier

Comment: Consider the points $(0,a)$ and $(0,-a)$ for small $a$.  Then they have a small Euclidean distance but there is no short path joining them.  Therefore the complement is not *locall* path-connected *as a subset of the plane*. @LoïcTeyssier

Comment: It is locally path-connected. There is no uniform $\epsilon$ such that all $\epsilon$-balls are path-connected.

Comment: @user83633, I gave a definition of what I mean by *local path-connectedness as a subset* in my question. Do me a favor and delete your answer.

Comment: No, please first find yourself a reasonable name for the concept you mean, and include a precise definition in the question. Then I will delete.

Comment: I did. What's unreasonable about "locally path-connected as a subset"?

Comment: The name "locally path-connected" is already taken. Maybe something like "uniformly locally path-connected" would be better.

Comment: OK let it be "tame".

Comment: @user83633, I would much appreciate if you could delete your answer so as not to give the impression to casual readers that the question has been answered.

Comment: Note that in the "earlier version" of the question, I *started* by saying that the space is obviously locally path-connected. Then I went on to define a different notion, that of path-connectedness as a subset. Your answer was *not* an answer to the earlier version of the question.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to reduce first to $x,y$ with $n$ distinct complex eigenvalues. Then the $n$ eigenvalues and eigenspaces of x are close to those of y. Now connect all those with paths (just make sure not to run through eigenvalue zero, and to keep invariance under complex conjugation).

Comment: Since the matrices are not assumed diagonalisable there may be no decomposition into eigenspaces.

Comment: But there is an arbitrarily short path to a diagonalizable matrix.

Comment: The problem is that things like Jordan block decomposition are not "stable", i.e., they tend to be discontinuous in the initial data. If you want to prove that *all* pairs of points can be so joined, this is an important concern.

Comment: The characteristic polynomial depends continuously on the matrix, the set of zeros of a polynomial depends continuously on the coefficients, and the the function sending a rank n-1 matrix to its kernel is also continuous. Using all this, the set of eigenvalues and eigenspaces of two close diagonalizable matrices are close.

Comment: I agree that the characteristic polynomial depends continuously, but the block decomposition does not.  You haven't really explained how to connect the matrices in a way that would depend continuously on the initial data. I am not saying you don't have a solution but I just don't see it yet.

Comment: You are right. Moving all eigenspaces of x to eigenspaces of y simultaneously is a problem.

Comment: I take it the other answer can be deleted at this point?